# Get profile data of facebook-user within webapplication by only logging into FB only one time

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

(hope my english is okay)

I looked all over the Developer Docs of Facebook and Google, but I can't find an answer that statisfies me. I hope you people over here can help me.

I am working on a webapplication where a user logs into (using the webapplications login-system). After logging in, the user can connect their facebook account to the application-account by signing into facebook and allowing my application to his/her profile-data.

When the user logs off from my application and logs in again on a different computer, my application should already know that it can access the facebook account of this specific user because he/she allowed this the first time.

My first thought is that I can achieve this by storing the user's facebook-ID in my application, so when the user logs into my application a second time I have his facebook-ID already, which allowes me (in combination with the app_access_token) to get the profile-data on the fly. **Is this thought correct or do I miss something?**

Hope you guys can explain me a little bit more about the concept of how to achieve this the correct way!

Answer (score 0):

Okay after 2 days of research I have almost proven my concept to be true! Here is how it works:

1) User logs into application

2) User connects to facebook and allowing my application to edit their facebook-data (application persmissions should have offline_access

3) Store the access_token you get back from facebook in the session in his application account

4) When users log in again on an other computer, check if there is a access_token for this user

4a) if there is an access_token make a api call setAccessToken(acces_token_you_have_stored)

4b) if there is no access token, the user did not yet allowed your application to user their data an proceed normal

5) do your next cool thing

Hope this information helps other people :)

Greets!